# Unexplained ping delay with "USB to Ethernet" adapter

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am running Linux with old kernel 3.10 on custom board with Huawei HiSilicon ARM Hi3536 chip.
The board includes 2 identical USB 2.0 ports. According to HW engineers there is nothing
in between of these two ports on PCB board and chip itself, only simple lines.

I am using the USB to Ethernet dongle "USB2-E100" with AX88178 chip.
The USB drivers used by that dongle are: asix.ko, usbnet.ko and static usbcore module in kernel.

I connect laptop directly to that "USB to Ethernet" dongle (no routers, switch etc in between).
I experience very strange behavior.

When I ping first usb port Round-trip time (RTT) is very stable under 1 ms.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 17:49 1-1 -> ../../../devices/platform/hiusb-ehci.0/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 17:49 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/hiusb-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0

C:\>ping -t 172.20.20.20

Pinging 172.20.20.20 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

However if I ping second usb port, every second ping has significantly longer RTT.

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 17:42 1-2 -> ../../../devices/platform/hiusb-ehci.0/usb1/1-2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 17:42 1-2:1.0 -> ../../../devices/platform/hiusb-ehci.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0

C:\>ping -t 172.20.20.20

Pinging 172.20.20.20 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=873ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=866ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=855ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=841ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=835ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=827ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time=812ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.20.20.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Can anyone advise what might cause this strange behavior?
The same drivers, identical configuration registers, both connected to the same USB hub ...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe interrupt routing? Are you using a terminal connected directly to the machine or are you using something like ssh to connect to the machine? If so which connection does it use?

Comment: @icarus As I said, I connect laptop directly to that "USB to Ethernet" dongle with ethernet cable (no ssh, no routers, switch etc in between).

Comment: OK, you have a laptop. you have a arm based computer running linux which has 2 USB ports. You have a usb to ethernet dongle. Are you running ping on the laptop or on the linux machine?

Comment: @icarus I run ping on Windows laptop and ping arm based computer running linux which has 2 USB ports. On both sides I have "USB to Ethernet" dongles, connected with ethernet cable.

Comment: Are you statically configuring the IP addresses? Do you have 1 or 2 dongles plugged into the 2 usb connectors on the arm machine? You say you have dongles "on both sides", do you mean you have dongles on both ends of the ethernet cable and that you are using a usb connection into your windows laptop? Where does the USB hub fit into the picture? Sorry about all the questions which seem obvious to you but remember we can't see your setup. Perhaps you could try and add some "ascii art" to show the setup?

Comment: @icarus Yes, IP addresses configured statically on both sides.

1 dongle at the time plugged into usb connector on arm machine. 

Yes, dongles are used on both ends of Ethernet cable.

On arm linux machine both usb ports sit on the same hub.

Port 1 on ARM is OK, Port 2 on ARM shows delay:

Comment: @icarus ARM, Linux <-> USB hub 1 <-> USB Port 1 <-> USB to Ethernet dongle <-> Ethernet cable <-> USB to Ethernet dongle <-> USB port <-> Windows Laptop

Comment: @icarus  ARM, Linux <->  USB hub 1 <-> USB Port 2 <-> USB to Ethernet dongle <-> Ethernet cable <-> USB to Ethernet dongle <-> USB port <-> Windows Laptop

Comment: Thanks. Next question. Is the "USB hub" just a chip on the arm machine or a different physical box? If the latter then my suggestion of interrupt routing is wrong. Am I correct that the ethernet cable and the 2 ethernet<->usb dongles remain the same in the two test cases? Another experiment you could do would be to reboot the linux box whilst connected to the second port, and see if the problem moves so port 2 is consistently fast and port 1 alternates fast and flow or if the problem remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119887/discussion-between-icarus-and-steeve007).